# Ormlite join foreign columns

Tags: java, android, database, join, ormlite

I have following datatable:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class TABLE_NAME {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private User createdUser;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private User updatedUser;
    ....

}
```

and how can I write following join query with ormlite?

```
select t.* from TABLE_NAME as t 
    LEFT join User as cu on (cu.id=t.createdUser.id)
    LEFT join User as uu on (uu.id=t.updatedUser.id)
where cu.userName="XXyy"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query needs some correction. I.e., second join is not being used. Alias `u` is undefined. If you require "XXyy" to be the creator, use an inner join.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the query, the above sql code works using rawQuery method, but ıs there any way to run with QueryBuilder.join ?